# TeamCity Projects and Multiple SVN Branches

Tags: version-control, teamcity

In the spirit of keeping my SVN trunk clean and ready for deployment, I've been utilizing [the following source control model](http://www.infoq.com/articles/agile-version-control). For the impatient, the basic concept is that you create development branches to do actual development, and leave the trunk clean and ready for deployment, at any time (no junk in the trunk).

In addition to this, I am configuring TeamCity for continuous integration. Within TeamCity, I'd like to ensure that all development branches, as well as the deployment-ready branch (the trunk, in my case) build correctly and pass all unit tests.

This might be a stupid question, but not being overly familiar with TeamCity, should I create a new TeamCity project for each branch? The deployment-ready branch, in particular, has a few additional rules than the development branch. For example, releases should be saved in versioned directories on the file system (e.g., C:\Projects\MyProject\1.0.187..., C:\Projects\MyProject\1.0.188...) to enable easy access to the binaries, at any point in time. On the other hands, saving versioned copies of the assemblies in the development branches is not necessary and would waste hard disk space.

Within TeamCity, I'd prefer to see only a single project for each software project. In other words, if my company is working on X number of development projects, I'd prefer to see that project listed only once, not X * 2 (assuming each project has only two branches).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only need to create a single project, but you will need multiple build configurations - 1 for each branch.  As far as I know, you can't customize the artifact folder name on disk (it's an auto-increment number), however you can download all artifacts as a zip file in TeamCity 4.5 from the UI.  There is also a scheduler included with TeamCity that lets you cleanup artifacts so they don't consume too much disk space.

Answer (score 2):

**TeamCity 2018.1.5**

[image]

TeamCity doesn't support multi branches for  SVN as for GIT - so I solved such problem with **Configuration parameter** - where I set active branch from which I need to build and after can easily switch to another branch by running a custom build or change that configuration parameter. 
[image]

After need just configures triggers to start building from a specific branch:

[image]

So on project side you can see different branches 
[image]

And easily switch between branches by running Custom Build and change branch there:

[image]