# Teamcity Project settings in SVN and branches

Tags: svn, teamcity, branch

I am using TeamCity to build a project hosted in an SVN Repo. I use one VCS root in project and checkout rules in each build configuration to be able to build feature branches. I think about using TeamCity feature "[Storing Project Settings in Version Control](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Storing+Project+Settings+in+Version+Control)".

Now the question: How is it possible to store the settings for each build configuration in the belonging branch? Is there an tricky solution?

When I activate the feature all settings of all build configurations are stored in VCS root, which is the level above the branches. My intention is that every branch can have its own TeamCity configuration which lies next to the code in SVN.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TeamCity Projects and Multiple SVN Branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893193/teamcity-projects-and-multiple-svn-branches)

Answer (score 0):

There's a [blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2018/01/branch-specific-settings-in-teamcity/) that explains how to implement the settings in branches.

You have to enable synchronization for the Versioned Settings in the Project configuration. That results in a .teamcity directory being added to the repository. Next, create a branch and edit the settings files in the branch. Note that not all the changes are effective in a branch as some of the settings, such as VCS are defined by the master branch.

Comment: Yes, that is the usual way to realize this with git. But with SVN it isn't possible I think. I have configured in project a VCS root (http://svn.local/repo) and for each branch there is a build configuration with checkout rules like "trunk", "branch/a" and so on. The .teamcity directory is placed in vcs root, which is in the level above. That's the problem.

Comment: @Pischke: Did you get anywhere with using TC and SVN?

Comment: @Rajesh I use git for new projects. For my old svn projects i wait for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-18911.